# Conditional match when comparing fields in multiple files using AWK

Tags: unix, awk, aix

I would like to find out how/whether it is possible to include some condition while comparing multiple fields from different files in AWK on AIX 6.x platform. Below is what I am trying to do:

```
Employee.txt (last column is the **status**)
1|canoeing|Sam|Smith|Seatle|X
2|jogging|Barry|Jones|Seatle|
3|football|Garry|Brown|Houston|
4|jogging|George|Bla|LA|X
5|basketballCeline|Wood|Atlanta|
6|tennis|Jody|Ford|Chicago|

Car.txt (last column is **availability**)
100|football|red|1|Y
110|tennis|green|9|N
120|hockey|yellow|2|N
130|football|yellow|6|N
140|jogging|red|8|Y
150|canoeing|white|0|
    
awk -F"|" '
NR == FNR {
   empcar[$3]
   next
}
{
   print > ($1 in empcar ? "match.txt" : "no_match.txt")
}' Car.txt Employee.txt
```

I like to check if the employee status is Active (no X) and the same for car availability (Y) before printing the matched record. Is this doable?

Thanks a lot,
George

Comment: Is column three in `car.txt` the employee number (column one of `employee.txt`)? Do you want to print the whole record from `employee.txt`? Join records from both files? Or just employee number?

Comment: It would help if you showed the desired output. I don't see any active employees with available cars in this sample data.

Comment: Column three of Car.txt is the employee number of Employee.txt. The desired output is a combination of records in both files. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can check for additional conditions in both files:

```sh
awk -F"|" '
NR==FNR {
   if ($NF == "Y")
      empcar[$(NF-1)]
   next
}
{
   print > ($NF != "X" && $1 in empcar ? "match.txt" : "no_match.txt")
}' Car.txt Employee.txt
```

Comment: The above code worked but I am trying to match 2 columns. Say I include another column ($2) called sport to Employee.txt & Car.txt and tried the following without success:
bash-4.3$ cat Employee1.txt
1|canoeing|Sam|Smith|Seatle|X
2|jogging|Barry|Jones|Seatle|
3|football|Garry|Brown|Houston|
4|jogging|George|Bla|LA|X
5|basketballCeline|Wood|Atlanta|
6|tennis|Jody|Ford|Chicago|
bash-4.3$ cat Car1.txt
100|football|red|1|Y
110|tennis|green|9|N
120|hockey|yellow|2|N
130|football|yellow|6|N
140|jogging|red|8|Y
150|canoeing|white|0|

Comment: The following AWK command failed to match the combination of employee number & sport fields in Car.1.txt & Employee1.txt. 
bash-4.3$ awk -F"|" ' NR==FNR { if ($NF == "Y") car[$4,$2]=$0; next } { print > ($NF != "X" && ($1,$2) in car ? "match.txt" : "no_match.txt") }' Car1.txt Employee1.txt
The content of no_match.txt is the same as Employee1.txt which is incorrect.

Comment: How to update my question with formatted example? I thought I can only add comments. Thanks

Comment: The following AWK command failed to match the combination of employee number & sport fields in Car.txt & Employee.txt. 

awk -F"|" ' NR==FNR { if ($NF == "Y") car[$4,$2]=$0; next } { print > ($NF != "X" && ($1,$2) in car ? "match.txt" : "no_match.txt") }' Car.txt Employee.txt 

The content of no_match.txt is the same as Employee.txt which is incorrect.

Comment: Question just says `I like to check if the employee status is Active (no X) and the same for car availability (Y) before printing the matched record` and that's what I did in my answer. Please update requirements  and show your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk '
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="|" }
FNR==NR{
  arr[$1]=$NF
  arr1[$1]=$0
  next
}
arr[$3]!="X" && $NF=="Y"{
  print arr1[$3] > ("match.txt")
  arr2[$3]
}
END{
  for(i in arr1){
    if(!(i in arr2)){
      print arr1[i] > ("no_match.txt")
    }
  }
}
' Employee.txt car.txt
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                      ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="|" }                        ##Setting FS and OFS to | in BEGIN section.
FNR==NR{                                   ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when Employee.txt is being read.
  arr[$1]=$NF                              ##Creating array arr with index of $1 and value of last field.
  arr1[$1]=$0                              ##Creating array arr1 with index of $1 and value of current line.
  next                                     ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
arr[$3]!="X" && $NF=="Y"{                  ##Checking condition if arr array with index of 3rd column value is not X and last field is Y then do following.
  print arr1[$3] > ("match.txt")           ##Printing respective entry from Employee.txt into match.txt file here.
  arr2[$3]                                 ##Creating an entry in arr2 with index of $3 here.
}
END{                                       ##Starting END block of this awk program from here.
  for(i in arr1){                          ##Traversing through arr1 here.
    if(!(i in arr2)){                      ##Checking if i(current item index) is NOT present in arr2 then do following.
      print arr1[i] > ("no_match.txt")     ##Printing respective value to no_match.txt file.
    }
  }
}
' Employee.txt car.txt                     ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: Please use more descriptive array names. `arr` and `arr1` don't help demonstrate the point.

Comment: @glennjackman, thanks for feedback Glenn. I usually do that, this time missed it, will try to change it, thanks.

Comment: I got no output from running this piece of code. Thanks for the effort though.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
awk -F'|' 'FNR==NR { empcar[$3]; next } $1 in empcar && $5 != "X"' cars emps
```

Output:

```
2|Barry|Jones|Seatle|
6|Jody|Ford|Chicago|
```

Comment: I got the following output:
1|Sam|Smith|Seatle
2|Barry|Jones|Seatle
6|Jody|Ford|Chicago

Thanks for your effort.

Comment: That sounds like a formatting issue with the input files. Do you have trailing whitespace the employee file?